# Is there any good book to compare western philosophy with Hindu philosphy?

Tags: philosophy, death, life

I feel like the Western philosophy is inherently depressing and their world-view is mostly nihilistic, I want to juxtapose the Western philosophies with Hindu/Indian philosophy. Are there any good books or texts on this?

I want to understand where the two philosophies stand on major issues of life and death, morality, purpose and relationships.

Comment: First of all there no one Western philosophy. Which theory do you adhere to?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/in.gov.ignca.7229/page/n1/mode/2up   in two volumes,                                                                                              https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey                                                                                                     https://archive.org/details/DialecticSpiritualismHisDivineGraceA.C.BhaktivedantaSwami/mode/2up      and the one you are searching for

Comment: @KrsnaDasa wow thank you, this is precisely what I was looking for. Which one will you recommend the most?

Comment: "A Critical Survey" only does passing comaprisons. Two better ones, although I take exception to some of their interpretations of advaita, are "Nonduality: A Study of Comparative Philosophy" by David Loy and (difficult to find) "Philosophy East/West: A Critical Comparison of Indian, Chinese, Islamic, and European Philosophy" by Ben-Ami Scharfstein, Ilai Alon, Shlomo Biderman, Dan Daor, and Yoel Hoffmann.